# python 2 - using variables inside method from another class

Tags: python-2.7

```
class A():
    def __init__():
        self.fields()

    def fields():
        ### code to display entry_field for user input

    def user_entry(self):
        club_name_existing  = entry_field.get()

class B():
    def __init__():
        pass

    def load_entry():
        db = create_engine('sqlite:///' + A.club_name_existing + '.db')
```

i need to run code similar to this but cannot get access to variable "club_name_existing".
the catch to my question is that i CANNOT put method inside **init**() for classA

Comment: You should consider declaring them as class variables. As it is now, it is local to that function.

Comment: there would be many variables to put and wouldnt look as organized if i did it that way. it would work but hoping to keep everything into methods for there purpose. easier to refer back to...EDIT, sorry i may have mis-understood your comment. did you mean by putting the variables inside class and not inside the method?

Answer (score 0):

If the value is shared between all instance of `A`, you can assign it to as a class variable:

```
def user_entry(self):
    A.club_name_existing = entry_field.get()
```

If it's potentially different for each instance, you'll have to pass an instance of `A` to either the `load_entry` method, or to the `__init__` of `B`. You'll have to choose which one is more appropriate in your case. For example:

```
def user_entry(self):
    self.club_name_existing = entry_field.get()

...

def load_entry(self, some_a):
    db = create_engine('sqlite:///' + some_a.club_name_existing + '.db')
```

Comment: the variable would not change, just would need to call it from another class like my example... would assigning it like you did allow me to use in my example? i am going to try it

Comment: do you think you could provide an example of passing instance to load_entry or __init__ of class b? thank you

Comment: @ricky6991 that's not enough information and the issue is likely in how you call those methods, not in this answer on its own... I would recommend you learning some more about how python objects work in general.